# Replacing a specific string in dataframe text within columns Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently having difficulty replacing a string in my pandas dataframe. So the string that I want to change is `"private"` -> `"pte"` and `"limited"` -> `"ltd"`.

The table looks like:

```
Column: Company_Name
 1. XXXX private limited
 2. XX (private) limited
 3. yyy pte. limited
```

My code is:

```
df['company_name'].str.replace('.*private.+*','pte')
df['company_name'].str.replace('limited$','ltd)
print(df)
```

But I still get the exact same dataframe that I used pandas to read. Does anybody know why - I checked that I imported re?

Comment: `str.replace` is not inplace, it returns the modified Series/column, you need to assign back: `df['company_name'] = df['company_name'].str.replace('.*private.+*','pte')`, check the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace)

Answer (score 2):

Look:

```
import pandas as pd

index = [1,2,3]
columns = ['company_name']
data =  ['XXXX private limited','XX (private) limited','yyy pte. limited']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)

df['company_name'] = df['company_name'].str.replace('private','pte')
df['company_name'] = df['company_name'].str.replace('limited$','ltd')
```

Result:

```
 company_name
1  XXXX pte ltd
2  XX (pte) ltd
3  yyy pte. ltd
```

Now, you have to search how to remove (). symbols.

Have a great day,

MARCUS

Answer (score 1):

str.replace is not an inplace operation, you have to assign the value back to df['company_name']

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is right.
Another choice is that you can use of propety of inplace.

And the code should be:

```
df['company_name'].str.replace('.*private.+*', 'pte' , inplace = True)
df['company_name'].str.replace('limited$', 'ltd', inplace = True)
```

Thus the dataframe `df` can be updated immediately

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for contributing! However, I'm pretty sure this does not work: `TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments`. Additionally, you are missing a terminating `'`